# If M is a closed subspace of X and $x ∈ X-M$ then $M + \mathbb Cx$ is closed.

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let X be a normed vector space.

If M is a closed subspace of X and $x ∈ X-M$ then $M + \mathbb Cx$ is closed.

where $M + \mathbb Cx=\{y+\lambda x:y\in M, \lambda\in \mathbb C \}$

the question comes from Folland's Real Analysis 2nd

5.2 linear functional Exercise 18.

I want to use Hahn-Banach theorem to find a continuous function on X, such that $M + \mathbb Cx$ is a inverse image of a closed set of this function, but I don't know how to construct this function and the closed set.

Comment: Plus, since this exercise is written for the section "linear functional" , I think we are supposed to use some results of linear functional. Indeed, there is a hint to the question saying that we may use theorem 5.8(a) on the page 159

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Any Cauchy sequence in $M +\mathbb{C}x$ will look like $m_n+\lambda_nx$ with $m_n$ a Cauchy sequence in $M$ and $\lambda_n$ a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: But X isn't necessarily complete, so $m_n$ may not converge to a point in M

Comment: @TiWen: In that case just edit the proof a bit. Suppose there is a limit point of $M+\mathbb{C}x$- say, $y$ and we have $m_n+\lambda_nx \rightarrow y$. Then, $\lambda_n$ is Cauchy, and hence converges to some $\lambda$. Now, look at $y-\lambda x$- one one hand, $m_n$ converges to $y-\lambda x$, and on the other hand, $M$ is closed. So $y - \lambda x \in M$. Hence proved.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still wondering how to proof the fact in your hint.

Comment: @TiWen: Any element of $M+\mathbb{C}x$ looks like $m+\lambda x$ with $m \in M$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. Now use my comment- my hint isn't as good as it indeed assumes that $X$ is closed- but as the comment points out- you can modify it to get a solution.

Comment: Sorry, I am not quite sure about your idea to the whole solution so I want to clarify it: to show $M+\mathbb C x$is closed, we pick a convergent sequence ${x_n}$ in $M+\mathbb C x$(thus it's Cauchy), we want to show its limit point lies in $M+\mathbb C x$. Your hint shows that we can split $x_n$ into two Cauchy sequences, your following comment shows that each of these two parts converges to a point and then $x_n$ converges to a point in $M+\mathbb C x$. So I still need to verify your hint in order to finish the whole proof.